# why is the toggle working only once for changing content?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const add = document.querySelector('i');
add.addEventListener('click', () => {
  add.classList.toggle('down');
  add.classList.toggle('up');
})
```

```css
i {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<button><i class="down"></button>
```

in this code  i want to create a button which have a value  i.e a down arrow and i am successfully able to get it. further i want this arrow to point upwards on click then again downward on second click and so on. for which i wrote a javascript which does its work as expected for the first time. but late on second click its not changing its direction to upward .
please tell me that where am i going wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to click on the button and not the icon. Your cursor is not always on the icon.

```
const add = document.querySelector('button');
      add.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let icon = add.querySelector('i')
        icon.classList.toggle('down');
        icon.classList.toggle('up');
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work fine. But there's only 1 issue. You are binding the click event to the `i` element. Therefore you need to click the `i` item. If you click on the `button` it feels like the event is not fired.

You can bind the click event to the `button`, and with `document.querySelectorAll('#toggle-button i')[0]` get the first `i` child of the button and toggle its classes.

```js
const parent = document.getElementById("toggle-button");
const child = document.querySelectorAll('#toggle-button i')[0];
parent.addEventListener('click', () => {
  child.classList.toggle('down');
  child.classList.toggle('up');
})
```

```css
i {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle-button"><i class="down"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the closing `</i>` tag.

```js
const add = document.querySelector('.toggle');
add.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const button = e.currentTarget;
  const icon = button.children[0];
  icon.classList.toggle('down');
  icon.classList.toggle('up');
})
```

```css
i {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="toggle"><i class="down"></i></button>
```

Comment: It's still not working if you click on the button but outside of the `i` child.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you are just adding the event listener to the small `i` element which can be tricky to click on. An easy way that you can add the event listener to the button (`i`'s parent) is by simply doing `add.parentElement.addEventListener()`:

```js
const add = document.querySelector("i");
add.parentElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
  add.classList.toggle("down");
  add.classList.toggle("up");
});
```

```css
i {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<button><i class="down"></i></button>
```